# Convert capitalized words only into lower case to cancels capitalization of nouns

Tags: awk, sed, grep, nlp, tr

Given :

```
$ cat input
Hello
Welcome
strIng
North Korea
USA
U.K.
```

I want to obtain:

```
$ cat output
hello
welcome
strIng
North Korea
USA
U.K.
```

**How to convert capitalized words* only to lower case ?**

*: first letter is capitalized.

Note: I look for a command which cancels the capitalization of nouns, while not attacking acronyms and weird words.

Comment: Although it is nice to have an example, you have to specify your requirements better.  How are `Hello` and `Welcome` different from `North`, `USA` and `U.K`?

Comment: `North Korea`, `USA` and `U.K` are lines with multiple upper cases.

Comment: So, if the third line were `StrIng` (both `S` and `I` upper case), your output should be same as input?

Comment: I think it this way : first character capitalized, then only lower case => transform all to lower case. So `StrIng` => `StrIng`, `strIng` = `strIng`, `STRING` => `STRING`, and `String` => `string`.<br>I look for a comman which cancels the capitalization of nouns, while not attacking the acronyms or willful weirdities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this will cover the sample input but not sure it's comprehensive of all other implied conditions

```
$ awk '/^[A-Z][^A-Z]+$/{$1=tolower(substr($1,1,1)) substr($1,2)}1' file
hello
welcome
strIng
North Korea
USA
U.K.
```

if first char matches an upper case and any subsequent chars are not, convert first char to lower case.

Comment: yes, but need to include the line boundary as well.

Comment: That would change the white space in the modified line which may not be desirable. `$0=tolower(substr($0,1,1)) substr($0,2)` wouldn't. Also, `[A-Z]` will include lower case letters in some locales, better to use the character class `[:upper:]` instead.

Comment: In `[A-Z][^A-Z]+$`, the `*` would be better so single-characters words are also covered (A=>a). It'sindeed not currently covered. @EdMorton suggests `/^[[:upper:]][^[:upper:]]*$` so to avoid the trap of `A-Z means "all upper and lower case letters except a".` Last, it would be wise to propose a variant considering spaces and dots.

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` solution:

```
sed '/^[A-Z][^A-Z]*$/ {
/^./y/ABCEDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcedefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/
}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Tested and confirmed to work for your example.  Modify to work for accented characters (not sure how well awk's `toupper` would do with them).

Comment: In some locales the collation order for letters is `aAbBcC...zZ` so `A-Z` means "all upper and lower case letters except `a`". Use character classes `/^[[:upper:]][^[:upper:]]*$` instead for portability.

Comment: @EdMorton +1.  Could you extend that to the transliteration as well?